# dart.html is not found when i build android or ios build in flutter

Tags: flutter, websocket, flutter-web

I am trying to develop an app which supports three platforms Android, Ios and Web and I have a socket implementation in the app, for socket I am using [web_socket_channel 1.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel).
But for web I have to use HtmlWebSocketChannel class which is not working in android or ios build and for android or ios I have to use IOWebSocketChannel which is not working in web build and give compile-time error.

For Web

> HtmlWebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(strong text'wss://echo.websocket.org'))

For Mobile build

```
IOWebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('wss://echo.websocket.org')),
```

Comment: Check the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710226/how-to-import-platform-specific-dependency-in-flutter-dart-combine-web-with-an/58713064#58713064). You will have to implement platform specific code for both and conditionally import them through a stub class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710226/how-to-import-platform-specific-dependency-in-flutter-dart-combine-web-with-an/58713064#58713064