# Error uploading a photo to Firebase storage with Flutter Web using Pickers

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I [read](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/3917) that [Firebase storage](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/overview/) is now compatible with Flutter web.
I have this code with which I'm able to upload photos with my android version, but I keep getting this error in web. `putfile()` triggers the error:

```
Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
```

My method for uploading looks like this:

```
  uploadImage() async {
    final _picker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile image;
    if(kIsWeb){
      image = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      var file = File(image.path);
      if (image != null)
      {
        var snapshot = await _storage.ref()
            .child('descriptionimages/'+widget.activity.id)
            .putFile(file);
        var downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      }
      else print('No Path Received');
    }
  }
```

The problem could also be linked to the [image picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) that I'm using. In the Readme it says: `Note that on the web platform (kIsWeb == true), File is not available, so the path of the PickedFile will point to a network resource instead.`

**UPDATE**
I installed this [FilePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) and changed the code to make it like this:

```
  uploadImage() async {
    final _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    PickedFile image;
    if(kIsWeb){
      FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
      if (result != null)
      {
        File file = File(result.files.single.path);
        var snapshot = await _storage.ref()
            .child('descriptionimages/'+widget.activity.id)
            .putFile(file);
        var downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        setState(()
        {
          widget.activity.image = downloadUrl;
          ActivityService().updateActivity(widget.activity);
        });
      }
      else print('No Path Received');
    }
}
```

Still, I get another error here in `File file = File(result.files.single.path)`. The path is null and it results in an error. [It seems that this plugin has the path null](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/API#methods).

Is there any suggestion? I'll continue my research for a Picker that supports paths in web.

Comment: Have you updated the plugin?

Comment: Which one are you refering to? I have versions just like in [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/overview/), [same with image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker).

Answer (score 2):

//This should be the correct code, happy coding!

uploadImage() async {

```
final _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
PickedFile image;
if(kIsWeb){
  FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
  if (result != null)
  {
    File file = File(result.files.single.bytes);
    var snapshot = await _storage.ref()
        .child('descriptionimages/'+widget.activity.id)
        .putData(file);
    var downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    setState(()
    {
      widget.activity.image = downloadUrl;
      ActivityService().updateActivity(widget.activity);
    });
  }
  else print('No Path Received');
}
```

}

Comment: Your solution looks cleaner than mine, good job!

Answer (score 1):

These guys [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604931/flutter-web-firebase-storage-missingpluginexception-no-implementation-found-fo) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719724/flutter-web-upload-to-firestore) had the answer some months ago (my respects).

My code results to be like this and it works:

```
uploadImage() async {
    final _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    final _picker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile image;
    if(kIsWeb){
      image = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      var bytes = await image.readAsBytes();
      if (image != null)
      {
        var ref= _storage.ref();
        var snapshot = await ref.child('descriptionimages/'+widget.activity.id)
            .putData(bytes);
        var downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        setState(()
        {
          ...
        });
      }
      else print('No Path Received');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use path on web using file_picker because paths are fake instead you must use bytes to pick up files and then use putData on firebase storage.

Answer (score 0):

In web you have to set metadata and use putData instead of putFile:

```
final metadata = firebase_storage.SettableMetadata(
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    customMetadata: {'picked-file-path': file.path});

if (kIsWeb) {
  uploadTask = ref.putData(await file.readAsBytes(), metadata);
} else {
  uploadTask = ref.putFile(io.File(file.path), metadata);
}
```

You can see the complete example in https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage/example