# Flutter Cross-Platform web and mobile

Tags: flutter, protocol-buffers, grpc-web

I'm trying to build a cross platform in flutter for web and mobile with protocol buffers. So, in my code i have a function to login and I need to import grpc_web:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart';
import 'package:dsu_site/models/user.pb.dart';
import 'package:dsu_site/models/user.pbgrpc.dart' as grpc;
import 'package:grpc/grpc_web.dart' as grpc_web;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:convert';



Future<Utilizador> login({String username, String password}) async {
  Utilizador user;

  if (kIsWeb) {
    final channel =
        grpc_web.GrpcWebClientChannel.xhr(Uri.parse('https://pl1772:8443'));
    final service = grpc.UtilizadoresServiceClient(
      channel,
    );

    var request = Auth();

    request.username = username;
    request.password = password;

    try {
      user = await service.login(request);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error in login form: $e');
      user = grpc.Utilizador();
    }
    return user;
  }

  final caCert = await rootBundle.loadString('certs/server.crt');

  final ClientChannel channel = ClientChannel(
    'localhost',
    port: 9002,
    options: ChannelOptions(
      connectionTimeout: Duration(seconds: 5),
      credentials: ChannelCredentials.secure(
        authority: 'localhost',
        certificates: utf8.encode(caCert),
      ),
    ),
  );

  final service = grpc.UtilizadoresServiceClient(channel);

  var request = Auth();

  request.username = username;
  request.password = password;

  try {
    user = await service.login(request);
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error in login form: $e');
    user = grpc.Utilizador();
  }

  return user;
}
```

The problem is when I run this for the web (using chrome) it's fine but for mobile, i get the following errors:

> Running "flutter pub get" in dsu_site... Launching lib/main.dart on
> sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...  lib/main.dart Invalid depfile:
> /home/sfm1977/Programming/dsu_site/.dart_tool/flutter_build/efe6e5ca256642d6c0ca767b5f0e6af5/kernel_snapshot.d Invalid depfile:
> /home/sfm1977/Programming/dsu_site/.dart_tool/flutter_build/efe6e5ca256642d6c0ca767b5f0e6af5/kernel_snapshot.d ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/grpc-2.7.0/lib/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart:17:8:
> Error: Not found: 'dart:html' import 'dart:html';
> ^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:6:8:
> Error: Not found: 'dart:html' import 'dart:html';
> ^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/grpc-2.7.0/lib/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart:40:9:
> Error: Type 'HttpRequest' not found.   final HttpRequest _request;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/grpc-2.7.0/lib/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart:168:27:
> Error: Type 'HttpRequest' not found.   void
> _initializeRequest(HttpRequest request, Map<String, String> metadata) {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/grpc-2.7.0/lib/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart:181:3:
> Error: Type 'HttpRequest' not found.   HttpRequest createHttpRequest()
> => HttpRequest();   ^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:34:18:
> Error: 'HttpRequest' isn't a type.   final _xhrs = {};
> ^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hostedthe fowling /pub.dartlang.org/grpc-2.7.0/lib/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart:40:9:
> Error: 'HttpRequest' isn't a type.   final HttpRequest _request;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/grpc-2.7.0/lib/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart:66:14:
> Error: Getter not found: 'HttpRequest'.
> case HttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED:
> ^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/grpc-2.7.0/lib/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart:69:14:
> Error: Getter not found: 'HttpRequest'.
> case HttpRequest.DONE:
> ^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/grpc-2.7.0/lib/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart:82:30:
> Error: 'ProgressEvent' isn't a type.
> _request.onError.listen((ProgressEvent event) {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/grpc-2.7.0/lib/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart:168:27:
> Error: 'HttpRequest' isn't a type.   void
> _initializeRequest(HttpRequest request, Map<String, String> metadata) {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/grpc-2.7.0/lib/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart:181:38:
> Error: The method 'HttpRequest' isn't defined for the class
> 'XhrClientConnection'.
>
> - 'XhrClientConnection' is from 'package:grpc/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart'
>   ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/grpc-2.7.0/lib/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
>   a method named 'HttpRequest'.   HttpRequest createHttpRequest() =>
>   HttpRequest();
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/grpc-2.7.0/lib/src/client/transport/xhr_transport.dart:200:11:
>   Error: 'HttpRequest' isn't a type.
>   final HttpRequest request = createHttpRequest();
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:58:34:
>   Error: 'Blob' isn't a type.
>   var blob = xhr.response as Blob ?? Blob([]);
>   ^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:46:15:
>   Error: The method 'HttpRequest' isn't defined for the class
>   'BrowserClient'.
> - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
>   a method named 'HttpRequest'.
>   var xhr = HttpRequest();
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:58:42:
>   Error: The method 'Blob' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
> - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
>   a method named 'Blob'.
>   var blob = xhr.response as Blob ?? Blob([]);
>   ^^^^ ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:59:20:
>   Error: The method 'FileReader' isn't defined for the class
>   'BrowserClient'.
> - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
>   a method named 'FileReader'.
>   var reader = FileReader();
>   ^^^^^^^^^^ Unhandled exception: FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml;
>   message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
>   [38;5;248m#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri
>   (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)[39;49m
>   [38;5;248m#1      asFileUri
>   (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:599:37)[39;49m [38;5;248m#2
>   writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:739:21)[39;49m
>
> [38;5;244m[39;49m [38;5;248m#3
> FrontendCompiler.compile
> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:554:15)[39;49m
>
> [38;5;244m[39;49m [38;5;248m#4
> _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:43:22)[39;49m
>
> [38;5;248m#5      starter
> (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:180:27)[39;49m
> [38;5;248m#6      main
> (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:13:30)[39;49m
>
> [38;5;244m#7      _startIsolate.
> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)[39;49m [38;5;244m#8
> _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)[39;49m
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script '/home/sfm1977/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle'
>   line: 900
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
> > Process 'command '/home/sfm1977/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 10s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)

Is it possible to run the two releases together, web and mobile?

Comment: please look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58713064/6813907

Comment: To much for me, i don't understand the code. I prefer to make two apps. Thanks

Comment: With some calm and patient i did it. Thanks

Comment: Hi @user4453709 How did you do it?

Comment: What happens if you remove this import 'package:grpc/grpc_web.dart' as grpc_web ?