# Error while running flutter web supporting application

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

My app has web support, and the web version works fine, but when I'm trying run this one on mobile I'm getting this error:

```
Invalid depfile: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\app\.dart_tool\flutter_build\242eec030db87a43f1788c8579309a46\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\app\.dart_tool\flutter_build\242eec030db87a43f1788c8579309a46\kernel_snapshot.d
lib/pages/web/application/add_application.dart:15:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' as html;
       ^
/D:/SDKFlutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_web-2.0.2/lib/image_picker_web.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
```

And the thing is that I don't actually need `dart:html` in my mobile version, but I need it on web one, **so is it able to run the app ignoring web files?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional import. Based on your platform you can use any optional package.
[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710226/how-to-import-platform-specific-dependency-in-flutter-dart-combine-web-with-an) and
[see this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/conditional-imports-across-flutter-and-web-4b88885a886e)

Simple way is make two widget and use ternary conditions, i.e.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

Container(
  child: kIsWeb ? WebPageUsedHTML() : NormalPage()
)
```