# web only code in a mobile flutter application

Tags: flutter

I need the import dart html (`import 'dart:html' as html;`) for the web version of my flutter app. Will using this import prevent me from building the iOS version of the app?

Comment: You should use conditional imports, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710226/how-to-import-platform-specific-dependency-in-flutter-dart-combine-web-with-an/58713064#58713064

Comment: Yes it will. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710226/how-to-import-platform-specific-dependency-in-flutter-dart-combine-web-with-an/58713064#58713064