# How to modify the following plugins for web in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

google_maps_flutter,
flutter_share,
path_provider ,
flutter_local_notifications,
geocoding,

These plugins does not work in web . what is the solution to modify this for web?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to replace the packages..

1. google_maps_flutter_web
2. share_plus
3. file_picker
4. awesome_notifications
5. google_geocoding

This is a link
[1]: https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_web
[2]: https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus
[3]: https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker
[4]: https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications
[5]: https://pub.dev/packages/google_geocoding

Comment: If I replace the packages it will not get supported in android and IOS. I need the app to run in all three platforms .

Comment: in that case, the only one  'google_maps_flutter_web' package is web-supported so you need to check the platform and  if the platform is web then use library 'google_maps_flutter_web' other vise 'google_maps_flutter'

like this link is more help full to you 
[click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254421/using-google-maps-in-flutter-for-both-mobile-and-web)

Comment: That generally entails a monorepo with a web package, vm package, and common package.  Be sure to look at package:melos for managing that setup.