# Flutter google map web marker on click

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter, google-maps-flutter-web

I am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_web) library in my app to load the Google map on the web using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71295511/2462531) answer as a reference, I am able to add the marker on it but wondering how I can do the marker on tap action

Adding marker:

```
final _icon = jsMap.Icon()
      ..scaledSize = jsMap.Size(60, 60)
      ..url = 'https://www.freeiconspng.com/thumbs/pin-png/pin-png-9.png';

final marker = jsMap.Marker(
      jsMap.MarkerOptions()
          ..position = latLng1
          ..map = map
          ..title = 'Test Title1'
          ..icon = _icon
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do the on click action using the below code:

```
final infoWindow =
        jsMap.InfoWindow(jsMap.InfoWindowOptions()..content = 'This is the content inside the Info window');
    marker.onClick.listen((event) => infoWindow.open(map, marker));
```

It may help someone!