# import dart:html Error while compiling android app

Tags: android, flutter, web

I have developed app which works on both Web and Android.
I have used 'dart:html' library to check app is resumed or pause.

But when I compiling app for android its giving error.

```
lib/controller/home_controller.dart:2
import 'dart:html';
       ^

Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
```

I need dart:html library to check app is resumed or paused.
My code :

```
  @override
  onInit() {
    super.onInit();

    if (isWebApp()) {
      window.addEventListener('focus', onFocus);
      window.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
    } else {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    }
  }

  void onFocus(Event e) {
    didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState.resumed);
  }

  void onBlur(Event e) {
    didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState.paused);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    printWithDateTime("111111");
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      getEmployee();
      homeDashboard();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to import a package based on the platform app will be running on, please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58713064/4224426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dart:html` can only be imported for web applications. I suggest to use [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) in your project instead. It's a package that still uses `dart:html` under the hood when using web, but allows you to import it in other platforms as well

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the import the following

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
```

Then any method used from the html package call it using html.Method()