# Compile different Section of the Code based on the Platform

Tags: flutter

I have a project for web and Android devices. The android application will show case user interface and the web will contain both user interface and admin interface.

Now, here is the Problem, There are some web packages that I am using like: dart.html and along with this package alot of dart code that is for Just for web,

Now, I build an APK file for the android application and it promote me these errors that says dart.html is being used.

I want to know is there a way we compile section of code depending upon the plate.

Here is the command that I used to build the APK file
`flutter build apk --release`

Here are some screenshots of when I build or compile code for Android devices.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulxxl.jpg)[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUz1M.jpg)[image]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBYQi.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 0):

To disable some parts of your code when you are running on an android device you can use the `kIsWeb` constant provided by flutter. You can do this like:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

if (kIsWeb) {
//Display your web UI
} else {
//Display your mobile UI
}
```

You also have conditional imports, but it is supported only for mobile and web. It is not supported for desktop versions. See: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34262#issuecomment-416129832
Also when importing packages, you need to use conditional imports for importing the platform specific package that you need. It works by checking if a package(platform-specific) exists at compile time :

```
// In this case I am showing using the dart:html package;
if (dart.library.html) 'package:flutter/yourwebpackage' 
if (dart.library.io) 'package:flutter/yourmobilepackage'
```

dart.html is only available for the web so this can be used as a condition for web apps.

dart.io is only available for native apps and not web apps, so we are using this as a condition for importing our other platform-specific package.

And if you are interested in another robust answer which will work on all cases with many packages, see: [How to import platform specific dependency in Flutter/Dart? (Combine Web with Android/iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710226/how-to-import-platform-specific-dependency-in-flutter-dart-combine-web-with-an/58713064#58713064)

Comment: Thank you, brother. I've tried this, but when I start compiling the project, it tells me that some components are only for the web, and it stops. However, I haven't tried conditional imports yet. So, let me try that.

Comment: Could you tell me the package your are working with. Also conditional imports should work in your case.

Comment: I am using dart.html and when I build the apk for android file then, I get this error saying that dart.html is being used.

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide the error messages and your code.

Comment: Sure, I can edit the question.

Comment: I have added some Screenshot, kindly check them out.